# How do I do this from nginx syntax in caddy v2?

Tags: nginx, webserver

How can I do this inside a reverse_proxy { ... } statement, done with nginx but I need to do it in caddy v2:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right:

```
    reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:8181 {
            header_up X-Real-IP {remote_host}
    }
```

Caddy restarted without errors. The other headers are handled by Caddy automatically. :)